React formatting a table
In React I am trying to render a table given a list of dictionary's. I am accomplishing that with the tbody tag and the data is being rendered but I am having difficulty with the formatting. There are some keys that have rather long names and they are getting wrapped based off of the length of the values inside of the dictionary's and this unfortunately is coming out as super ugly. How do I format cell boxes so the table widens out to accommodate long column names? Also how might I format a cell if there is missing/invalid data in it? For instance Sue has an empty string for state, is it possible to render that cell as all red to signal to the inputter that data is missing? Any help would be appreciated.
data = [{
    name: "Charlie",
    super_duper_uber_long_key: "ABC",
    state: "rested",
    medium_length_key: "c",
}
{
    name: "Sam",
    super_duper_uber_long_key: "ABC",
    state: "sleepy",
    medium_length_key: "a",
}
{
    name: "Sue",
    super_duper_uber_long_key: "ABC",
    state: "",
    medium_length_key: "b",
}]

function tableRender(data){
    return [
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>super duper uber long key</th> //every 4th letter is getting wrapped
        <th>state</th>
        <th>medium length key</th>   //this displays completely vertically
      </tr>
      {data.map((item, i) =>
       <tr key = {i}>
        <th>{item.name}</th>
        <th>{item.super_duper_uber_long_key}</th>
        <th>{item.state}</th>
        <th>{item.medium_length_keyy}</th>
       </tr>   
      )}
    </tbody>
];
}



Is using CSS not your solution? In design area, React is not opinionated.
